# How to pass JSON from Android to MVC controller?

Tags: c#, android, json, asp.net-mvc

In my latest project I want to have a user type in name and password on an Android phone, save it in JSON-format, and POST it to an ASP.NET MVC server which should return configuration data in a new JSON.

What I have so far:

Android (partial code):

```
String json = "{\"x\": \"val1\",\"y\":\"val2\"}";
URL url = new URL("http://xxxxx/Home/GetData");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");      // have tried without this
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", json.getBytes().length + "");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

The json string here is just for testing.

MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(String request)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(request.Length); // not relevant to the question

    var data = new { Name = "Test", Age = "39" };
    return Json(data);
}
```

Returns JSON with test data.

The string argument in the MVC controller is probably wrong here. I have tried accepting e.g. byte[], but I always end up with NULL.

Any help with this or suggestions for alternatives is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If this is what's being posted to the server:

```
{
  "x": "val1",
  "y": "val2"
}
```

Then the method parameters should reflect those key/value pairs.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetData(string x, string y)
```

Comment: What is being posted is a sequence of bytes from the original string. My my problem is how to receive them in the controller (which does not know about the contents of the json).

Comment: @ludolover: Is the content body of the post request somehow different because of the "bytes from the original string"?  What does the actual request look like when compared to just sending plain JSON in the request body?  What are you going to be doing with this data server-side that the server-side code doesn't know the structure of it?

Answer (score 0):

This will go through everything you post in the json. Prettu much like @David's but for when you have no clue whats being sendt to the `GetData`

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        //This will iterate through everything in your post data
        var value = Request.Form[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hehe:) Well, I'm still getting ArgumentNullException... Could I be missing some argument in the controller, or parameter in the URL request? The controller should be able to find the data in the body of the request, right?